# How to configure JSF 2.3 with Tomcat in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee-8

I am building JSF project, it is my first project, and when I am trying to run the program on the server which is tomcat-9 and no thing change in .xhtml file display on the browser.
May someone help me and explain how to configure IntelliJ with JSF ?

[see project structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z7UI.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many getting started sites.
For example https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javaserver-faces-jsf.html.